# Frame buffer object error?

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to implement a Framebuffer Object in my program. I have included

```
#include <GL/glew.h> 
#include <GL/glut.h>
```

I get the following errors:

```
 error: ‘glGenFrameBuffers’ was not declared in this scope

error: ‘GL_FRAME_BUFFER’ was not declared in this scope

error: ‘glBindFrameBuffer’ was not declared in this scope
```

My code to create the Framebuffer Object is as follows:

```
GLuint fbo;
glGenFrameBuffers(1 , &fbo);
glBindFrameBuffer(GL_FRAME_BUFFER, fbo);
```

When I run the following code to create a Vertex Buffer Object, the project compiles:

```
GLuint vbod;
glGenBuffers(1 , &vbod);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbod);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Framebuffer is considered one word, so use downcase `buffers` and remove the underscore from the constant:

```
GLuint fbo;
glGenFramebuffers(1 , &fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
```

Comment: @user2670468: To that end, if you acknowledge that `Framebuffer` is one word it is much clearer that they are not Buffer Objects. They are just objects whose name happens to end with "...buffer" ;) It is an important distinction for many things because Buffer Objects in OpenGL have unique properties when it comes to resource allocation, sharing, etc.